# Headers downloading actual page content, not the csv file I've constructed

Tags: php, csv, header

My goal here is to have the browser download a csv file using headers to do it. For some reason yet to be determined, the browser seems to be downloading the HTML content of the current page (and ***not*** the contents of the array I've given it).

Here is the code I've been using:

```
$arr1 = array(array("1","2","3","4"),array("2","1","6","6"));

$tmp_handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fputcsv($tmp_handle, $arr1);

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");

rewind($tmp_handle);
echo stream_get_contents($tmp_handle);
```

I've followed the instructions of many articles / SO questions I've read and I don't see what's wrong with this code.

I of course appreciate any help that I can get here!

Here is the complete code (upon request):

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

// Get total number of active referrers
$referrer_check = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer");
$num_of_referrers = 0;

foreach ( $referrer_check as $check) 
{
$num_of_referrers++;
}

// Get total number of referral transactions
$num_of_referrals = 0;
$num_referral_check = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer_transactions");
foreach ( $num_referral_check as $check) 
{
$num_of_referrals++;
}

// Check for the top referrer
$top_referrer = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT referrer_id, count(*) as row_count FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer_transactions GROUP BY referrer_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");
$top_referrer_result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer WHERE referrer_id = $top_referrer->referrer_id");

// Construct the table

// Create array for second table
$ref_transactions_table_arr = array(
array("Referee Name", "Referee ID", "Referee Sign Up", "Referee Email","Referrer ID","Referrer Name"));

foreach ($num_referral_check as $check) 
{
$ref_transactions_table_arr[] = array(
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT billing_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pmpro_membership_orders WHERE user_id = $check->buyer_id"),
$check->buyer_id,
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_registered FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users WHERE ID = $check->buyer_id"),
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users WHERE ID = $check->buyer_id"),
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT referrer_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer WHERE referrer_id = $check->referrer_id"),
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT referrer_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer WHERE referrer_id = $check->referrer_id")
);
}

// Create array for first table
$active_ref_table_arr = array(
array('Referrer Name', 'Referrer ID', '# of Referrals', 'Address','Referrer Email','Lifetime Referrals'));

foreach ( $referrer_check as $check) 
{
$active_ref_table_arr[] = array(
$check->referrer_name, 
$check->referrer_id,
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer_transactions WHERE referrer_id = $check->referrer_id"),
$check->referrer_street . " " . $check->referrer_city . ", " . $check->referrer_state . " " . $check->referrer_zip,
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users WHERE ID= $check->referrer_id"),
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."referrer_transactions WHERE referrer_id = $check->referrer_id")
);
}

// Download file
if(isset($_POST['export_tbl_one']))
{
$csvData = array(
  array("1","2","3","4"),
  array("2","1","6","6")
);

$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

/*foreach ($csvData as $row) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}*/

fputcsv($fp,$csvData);

rewind($fp);
$csvFile = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($csvFile));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');

exit($csvFile);
}

?>
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
                <li class="first"><a href="#">Total Referrers: <? echo $num_of_referrers;  ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Total Referals: <? echo $num_of_referrals; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Top Referrer: <? echo $top_referrer->referrer_id . ", " . $top_referrer_result->referrer_name . "(" . $top_referrer->row_count . ")"; ?></a></li>
<li>
<form method="POST" action="http://keepmecertified.com/acp">
<input type="submit" value="click me" name="export_tbl_one"/>
</form>

</li>
        </ul>
</div>

<br>

<table class="table">
<caption>Referrer Transactions</caption>
<?
$num = 0;

foreach($ref_transactions_table_arr as $fields)
{

  echo "<tr>";


    foreach($fields as $data)
    {

      if($num == 0)
      {
        echo "<th class=\"ref_head\">$data</th>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<td>$data</td>";
      }

    }


   echo "</tr>";

   if($num == 0)
   {
     $num++;
   }


}

?>
</table>

<table class="table">
<caption>Active Referrers</caption>
<?
$num = 0;

foreach($active_ref_table_arr as $fields)
{

  echo "<tr>";


    foreach($fields as $data)
    {

      if($num == 0)
      {
        echo "<th class=\"ref_head\">$data</th>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<td>$data</td>";
      }

    }


   echo "</tr>";

   if($num == 0)
   {
     $num++;
   }


}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried your snippet, and it works (the CSV part is Array,Array).  If there is more HTML content, you are not showing the whole snippet.

Comment: This is part of a WordPress script so I'm wondering if something before this script is messing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$csvData = array(
  array("1","2","3","4"),
  array("2","1","6","6")
);

$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
foreach ($csvData as $row) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

rewind($fp);
$csvFile = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($csvFile));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');

exit($csvFile);
```

I have looped the data to build the CSV as your code would not produce the result you expect. I have also retrieved the file as a string before outputting - this is just a nicety to add a `Content-Length` header. I have also - and this is the important bit - called `exit` to output the data, to prevent any more code being executed any prevent and HTML after this code being output.

If you are using this code and still having a problem, then the code is not being called - you should check any `if` statements etc that this code is wrapped in.

Comment: When I use this code, the csv only contains the following:

`<!DOCTYPE HT `

By the way, the code MUST be getting called because a CSV file ***is*** being downloaded.

Comment: It's very important, that no output happens before the csv file output. Please post a link to the whole wordpress plugin php.

Comment: I can tell you what the problem is but you'll have to add the **entire script** to the question to pinpoint it. You are getting that result because of the `Content-Length` header I added.

Comment: @Evan I can only assume that the script above is included by another script, since it does not contain the start of the HTML document (`<!DOCTYPE...`). This other script is already outputting data before the code above is called. You should put the entire `if(isset($_POST['export_tbl_one']))` section in the parent script, **before** the start of the HTML output. This will solve the problem. You also **must** use the loop on the csv data or the file will contain `Array,Array` - `fputcsv()` writes **one row at a time** and expects an array of strings.

Comment: This is a wordpress PAGE - so, the headers.php script which runs before all pages has the HTML stuff in it. Let me go try your suggestion now!

Comment: Note that this tallies with the output you are getting, since `strlen("Array,Array\n") === strlen("<!DOCTYPE HT")`

Comment: @Evan your server has output buffering enabled, which is why you were able to modify the headers at this point - normally this would throw a warning and you may have found the problem quicker. Keep in mind that anything outside the `<?php ?>` tags is written *directly* to the output buffer, and if you want to send a file you must ensure that the file is the *only* thing in the output buffer, or it will be corrupted when it arrives at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is way late but let's hope this unblocks someone.

Use `ob_end_clean()` to clean out other buffers on the page.

Start with `ob_end_clean();` and end with `exit;`

This way, only the output in between will be written to the file.